# Missing index in key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, ddl

Im having an error with constraints, it is specific in the index of fk_Pedido4, last paragraph, it would help a lot if someone can help.

```
CREATE TABLE Cliente (
    CPF real PRIMARY KEY,
    Nome Varchar (55),
    Endereco VARCHAR (55),
    Contato real
);

CREATE TABLE Funcionarios (
    Registro INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Carteira_Trabalho REAL,
    Nome varchar(55),
    Contato REAL,
    CNH REAL,
    Tipo_Funcionario INT
);

CREATE TABLE Pizza (
    Codigo INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Sabores CHAR,
    Ingredientes CHAR
);

CREATE TABLE Pedido (
    Numero INT,
    Observacoes VARCHAR(55),
    Cliente real,
    Data DATE,
    Hora TIME,
    Pizza INT,
    Codigo_Cozinheiro INT,
    Codigo_Atendente INT,
    Codigo_Entregador INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Numero, Data)
);
 
ALTER TABLE Pedido ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Pedido_2
    FOREIGN KEY (Cliente)
    REFERENCES Cliente (CPF)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT;
 
ALTER TABLE Pedido ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Pedido_3
    FOREIGN KEY (Pizza)
    REFERENCES Pizza (Codigo)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT;
 
<sub>ALTER TABLE Pedido ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Pedido_4
    FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_Cozinheiro, Codigo_Atendente, Codigo_Entregador)
    REFERENCES Funcionarios (Registro, Registro, Registro)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;</sub>
```

Im just expecting a syntax error that Im not seeying due to lack of experience in this language...

Comment: ' in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Some side notes: 1. `REAL` is an approximate type. We usually don't use approximate data types in a database if we can avoid that. Use a precise type instead. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html. 2. You should mark all columns that must not be null `NOT NULL`. 3. Be consistent with your names. In Funcionarios you call their ID Registro, in Pedido you call it Codigo.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key says there must be exactly one row with the given key in the parent table.

```
ALTER TABLE Pedido ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Pedido_4
FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_Cozinheiro, Codigo_Atendente, Codigo_Entregador)
REFERENCES Funcionarios (Registro, Registro, Registro)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Here you say the parent table Funcionarios must have a row where its key (Registro, Registro, Registro) matches Pedido (Codigo_Cozinheiro, Codigo_Atendente, Codigo_Entregador). First, there is no key (Registro, Registro, Registro) in Funcionarios. The key is the single column (Registro). And even if we would create such a key, there would be no row where Registro matches all of Codigo_Cozinheiro, Codigo_Atendente, and Codigo_Entregador at the same time.

You want a foreign key for each of the codigos instead, so Codigo_Cozinheiro must have a match in Funcionarios, and Codigo_Atendente must have a match in Funcionarios, and Codigo_Entregador must have a match in Funcionarios.

```
ALTER TABLE Pedido ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Pedido_4
FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_Cozinheiro)
REFERENCES Funcionarios (Registro)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Pedido ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Pedido_5
FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_Atendente)
REFERENCES Funcionarios (Registro)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Pedido ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Pedido_6
FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_Entregador)
REFERENCES Funcionarios (Registro)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```